# Honeywell water heater gas control valve pilot won't stay lit

Tags: natural-gas

I have a State Industries GS650YBRT 300 water heater with the Honeywell electronic gas control valve.

This hot water heater will not light.

I am able to get the pilot light to light and after a short delay, the indicator light on the control valve LED status light begins to flash normally.

At this point, the pilot button should be able to be released and the pilot light remains lit in order to select an operating temperature on the control knob.  However, as soon as the pilot button is released, the pilot light extinguishes, regardless of how long it is held in after the pilot light initially ignites.

Obviously the system is sensing the pilot light being lit in order to cause the control valve LED status light to flash.  The status light flashes once every 3 or 4 seconds and does not indicate any faults, so why will the pilot light not remain lit?

Comment: Please post pictures. Especially of the pilot, gas valve and burner areas. It sounds like the thermocouple isn't heating up enough to keep the gas valve open. That can happen if the sensor is bent or mis-aligned with the burner or pilot flame. (Sometimes they get bumped or whatever.) If you need it, here's a link to the owner's manual: https://www.statewaterheaters.com/lit/im/res-gas/184165-003.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The device probably has more than one pilot light sensor...for safety.  The electronic one is saying OK, but a physical backup sensor may not be detecting the pilot flame.

If there is a small rod in the path of the pilot flame (the physical sensor), you might try cleaning it with a bit of emery cloth or steel wool.